# InflateException ( error inflating class TextView) with AS Hedgehog

Tags: android, android-layout

I just upgraded Android Studio to Hedgehog and get now an InflateException which did not occur before. The call stack shows that the exception occurs during the call to **setContentView **in the activity's OnCreate method.
What changed with Hedgehog causing this problem?

---

**Result:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de. myapp.myapp_1, PID: 5888
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{de.myapp.myapp_1/de. myapp.myapp_1.act.MyAppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111 in de. myapp.myapp_1:layout/activity_myappmain: Binary XML file line #111 in de. myapp.myapp_1:layout/activity_myappmain: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111 in de. myapp.myapp_1:layout/activity_myappmain: Binary XML file line #111 in de. myapp.myapp_1:layout/activity_myappmain: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111 in de. myapp.myapp_1:layout/activity_myappmain: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f04010f a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:597)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3989)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1089)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:113)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:228)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:148)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
    at de. myapp.myapp_1.act.MyAppActivity.onCreate(MyAppActivity.java:258)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)


    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I did already an "Invalidate Caches and Restart" (which was necessary to get rid of errors displayed in the Manifest file).
XML Code for the TextView:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTestFunc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="64sp"
            android:text="tvFuncTest"
            **android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"**
            android:typeface="normal" />
```

---

If I remove the "android:textcolor" line from the above XML, the TextView is processes correctly (as it did with AS 2022).

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake by you that is you've typed `**android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"**` instead of `android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"` so just remove the ** from start and end.
Here is the corrected code

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTestFunc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:minHeight="64sp"
                android:text="tvFuncTest"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                android:typeface="normal" />
```

Comment: sorry for that, I tried to format this line as bold text. In the XML file, it is correct.

Comment: to make text bold use the property
android:textStyle="bold"